# How to search for only shortcuts on Google Drive

Tags: shortcuts, google-drive, file-shortcut

Google Drive rolled out the new shortcuts which will soon replace the "one file in multiple folder" feature (to be deprecated by September 30).

Now the question is if we create shortcuts of the file, how do we search for only those shortcuts?

Answer (score 0):

At drive.google.com you can click the drop-down arrow on the right of the search box and choose **shortcuts**
Or use this syntax:

```
type:shortcut your file name
```

[image]